# SSO (Single Sign On): How to share keycloak session between two applications

Tags: single-sign-on, microservices, jhipster, openid-connect, keycloak

I have a monolithic Spring Boot application generated by jhipster and microservice gateway also by jhipster. Both are secured with keycloak OpenID. I need both monolithic and microservice gateway work with same keycloak token.

Both apps are configured to use SSO in SecurityConfiguration and both use the same client on keycloak (named "web_app" in default jhipster-provided keycloak config) and I can authenticate with same credentials on both apps. But when I login in monolith it signs me out of gateway (miscroservice app) and visa versa.

How can I configure SSO (e.g. authentication in any of my applications and using same keycloak session on all of them) in my jhipster generated Spring Boot app?

Thank you :)